# ComposeOptions.kotlinCompilerVersion is deprecated. Compose now uses the kotlin compiler defined in your buildscript

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am unable to build my project have tried many things still not able to build the project here is the gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0-beta01'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here is the `app/build.gradle file`

```
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.plcoding.jetpackcomposepokedex"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.30'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha06'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"

    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha04"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha09"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-alpha05"

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0"

    // Timber
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.3'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1"

    // Coil
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil:1.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-coil:0.7.0"

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.33-beta"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.33-beta"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-beta01"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha01'

    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

so i am still unable to figure out what is causing the issue here please help

the error that i am getting
`ComposeOptions.kotlinCompilerVersion is deprecated. Compose now uses the kotlin compiler defined in your buildscript.` 
please help
I have already tried all the things from internet still can't build my project please help here

Please tell me in detail about the problem and how to resolve any such issues if i again encounter them in furture